# Topology general of subsets and a base whith no especification.

Tags: general-topology

For each real $x$ we define $B(x)$ as the collection of all the open intervals centered in $x$ while the elements of $B(0)$ will be of the forms $\left(-\infty, -n \right) \cup \left(-e,e\right) \cup \left(n, \infty\right)$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $e>0$. Show that this is a base.
Is hard totrhink but i just understand what a base is.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Could you please write down the definition of the base and hence what would be required to show the given is a base?

Comment: In your 1st line I think you mean for each real $x\ne 0$. If so, please edit. Do you want to show it is a base for the standard topology, or to show it is a base for a topology?